# Count extracted values from Pandas value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas

It seems simple but I haven´t found it exactly in other answers.

How to assign to some variable the count of some condition in pandas, as example below:

Command (to count the categories of a column in pandas dataframe):

```
print(data.isBald.value_counts())
```

Output:

```
 Bald 2345
 notBald 5432
Name: isBald, dtype: int64
```

Question is:

```
isBaldCount = ?  #2345
```

The result was print but how to assign it to a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want the count of `Bald` people (!!), then use -

```
isBaldCount = data.isBald.eq('Bald').sum()
```

On the other hand, if you want to count every value and assign it to separate variables, then use `value_counts` and assign the result -

```
c = data.isBald.value_counts()

isBaldCount = c.loc['Bald'].item()
notBaldCount = c.loc['Not Bald'].item()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
outdf = pd.DataFrame(data.isBald.value_counts())
outdf.loc[outdf.index == 'Bald',:]
```

Comment: thank you Aidan, I accepted the other answer as I get "isBaldCount" in one single line.